# $-5| 2+4x | = -32(x+3/4)- | x | + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This was my attempt:
$$-5| 2+4x | = -32\left(x+\frac34\right)- | x | + 1\\
\implies|2+4x|=\frac{-32x-24- | x | + 1}{-5}\\
\implies2+4x=\pm \frac{-32x+-24- x  + 1}{-5}\\
\implies4x=\pm \frac{-33x+-23 }{-5}-2\\
\implies-20x=\pm (-33x-23)+10\\
\implies-20x= -33x-13\text{ or} -20x=33x+33\\
\implies13x= -13\text{ or} -53x=33\\
\implies x=-1\text{ or} x=-\frac{33}{53}$$
Neither of these answers works when checking.
Using a graphing calculator I get an answer of $\frac{-11}{17}$ which does check, but I don't know how to get that answer using algebraic means.

Comment: second to third you set $|x| = x$. You should simply separate the equations instead of using $\pm$, this will lead to confusion.

Comment: consider the three cases $x \le -\frac{1}{2}$, $-\frac{1}{2} < x \le 0$, and $x > 0$ separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake between the second and the third line:
$$|2+4x|=\frac{-32x-24- | x | + 1}{-5}\\
2+4x=\pm \frac{-32x-24- \color{red}{x}  + 1}{-5}\\$$ instead it should have been $$2+4x=\pm \frac{-32x-24- \color{red}{|x|}  + 1}{-5}.\\$$
Going on you get
$$-10-20x=\pm(-32x-24- |x| + 1)$$
Now you should treat the 2 cases ($x\ge0$ and $x\lt0$) differently:
\begin{cases}
x\ge0 \to -10-20x=\pm(-32x-24- x+ 1)\\
x\lt0 \to -10-20x=\pm(-32x-24+x+ 1)
\end{cases}\begin{cases}
x\ge0 \to x=-\frac{33}{13} \lor -\frac{13}{53} \text{ solutions not acceptable}\\
x\lt0 \to x=-\frac{13}{11} \lor x=-\frac{11}{17}
\end{cases}
So the final solutions are $$x=-\frac{13}{11} \lor x=-\frac{11}{17}$$

Comment: yes, sorry...I'm correcting ;)

Comment: OK, I think that I have it. I am getting some different answers, for instance when $$x\ge 0$$ I get $$-10-20x=(-32x-24-x+1)\to x=-1$$ and for $$-10-20x=-(-32x-24-x+1)\to x=\frac {-33}{53}$$. My answers for for $$x<0$$ were the same as yours. Plugging those values back into the original equation the only one that worked was $$\frac {-11}{17}$$ My only question now is how should I have known that when x<0, (-32x-24-|x|+1) became (-32x-24+x+1)? I am kind of guessing it is because it was the negative of a negative.

Comment: Well, for the first question, note that the full equation is $$-10-20x=\color{red}{\pm}(-32x-24- x+ 1)$$As regards the second question you know that $$x \lt 0 \Rightarrow |x| = -x \Rightarrow -|x| = -(-x)=+x=x$$

Comment: Thank You for all the help, hope that you have a good day.

Comment: Hope you too!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

There are two equations here. When you have absolute value, you have to have one equation where you use the original and another where the stuff inside the absolute value signs is negative. So try solving the equation where the stuff in the absolute value signs are negative.